# Import Error: cannot import 'mdss_bias_scan' from 'aif360.sklearn.metrics'

Tags: python, aif360

I would like to use the mdss_bias_scan function of aif360 for detecting the combination of variables that make up the privileged group and the non-privileged group.

When I try to import the function:
`from aif360.sklearn.metrics import mdss_bias_scan`

I get the following error:
`Import error: cannot import 'mdss_bias_scan' from 'aif360.sklearn.metrics'`.

Can you help me to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

The function `mdss_bias_scan` is not available in the version of `aif360` you're using (`v0.4.0`).

Here's the [source code](https://github.com/Trusted-AI/AIF360/blob/v0.4.0/aif360/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py) of the file `metrics.py` at tag `v0.4.0`.

The function `mdss_bias_scan` was added via [this commit](https://github.com/Trusted-AI/AIF360/commit/9860dc7abcd9109cf2f77605591ccfb0da050402) which has not yet been released.

---

From the [GitHub Source](https://github.com/Trusted-AI/AIF360/blob/master/aif360/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py#L26), it seems that you should import it as:

```
from aif360.sklearn.metrics.metrics import mdss_bias_scan
```

Also, make sure you have `aif360` package installed in your Python environment. If not, install it using:

```
pip install aif360
```

Comment: Thanks, I Have already installed aif360 package

Comment: @Amanda Did that solve the problem?

Comment: No, I have encountered the same error. When I try to import other functions from the same library, I haven't the same error message. So, could the problem is with mdss_bias_scan?

Comment: @Amanda Could you mention the version of `aif360` that's currently installed? It can be viewed with `pip show aif360` command.

Comment: The version installed is 0.4.0 
It should be the leatest one

Comment: That explains it. `mdss_bias_scan` is not available in `metrics` in their `v0.4.0` release. I'll updated my answer accordingly.